# Defining a time slot in Org Agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

When in Org Agenda `C-S` on a task allows to set a date and a time, like for example `SCHEDULED: <2020-10-20 mar. 10:00>`. I'd like to set a time slot (e.g. from 10:00 to 12:00) instead of an hour (e.g. 10:00).

Comment: Doesn't typing `10:00-11:00` work? It works for me - you might want to clarify the question with an example otherwise. But note that `SCHEDULED` probably [does not mean what you think it means](https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-Scheduling.html#Deadlines-and-Scheduling) - read the `Important:` note on that page.

Comment: Thanks again NickD, 10:00-11:00 does the trick.

Comment: Thanks!, It's a very useful feature I started using it

Answer (score 1):

Simply write `<2020-10-20 mar. 10:00-12:00>` instead. If you have the timegrid enabled you'll even be able to see the time span.